# two gpu two x session, move mouse from one x server to the other

Tags: xorg, gpu

and xinerama sucks.. So I thought I might use two x servers.. but I do not understand how I move the mouse courser from one screen to the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed, it has all the details needed.
http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/moving-the-mouse-between-separate-screens-in-a-single-x-session/

http://de.mcbf.net/david/dualscreenmouseutils/